# How to use IN operator in Cakephp

Tags: php, sql, cakephp

> For CakePHP version 2.x. If $trs is an array of user id, you don't have to put IN keyword to your conditions. You can leave just array("Post.user_id" => $trs) and Cake add IN operator to this query. Whole line:

$this->Post->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('Post.user_id'=>$trs),
'order' => array('Post.created DESC')));

Comment: Your edit actually makes this question *worse*. Not better.

Answer (score 5):

For CakePHP version 2.x. If `$trs1` is an array, you don't have to put `IN` keyword to your conditions. You can leave just `array("Post.user_id" => $trs1)` and Cake add IN operator to this query. Whole line:

```
$this->Post->find('all',array(
    'conditions'=> array('Post.user_id' => $trs1), 
    'order' => array('Post.id DESC')
));
```

Comment: Note that this is only valid for 2.x - in CakePHP 3.x you will have to add `IN`.

Comment: Oh, thanks, I haven't looked at 3.x version yet.

Comment: Also valid for cake 1.3